# Java - Selenium Webdriver: Entering text into text field, and removes automatically from the text field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

when i enters the text into the field it gets removed automatically after entering.

```
String barcode="0000000047166";

WebElement element_enter = _driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='div-barcode']"));

element_enter.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/form/div/div/input")).sendKeys(barcode);
```

Comment: Your second XPath expression try to find an `html` tag but you are already searching in the limited context of the first element (`element_enter`). I don't think this can work.

Comment: it's working but problem is text is removed before next action.

Comment: Is there any Ajax or JavaScript action bound to that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a case where I was entering text into a field after which the text would be removed automatically. Turned out it was due to some site functionality where you had to 
press the enter key after entering the text into the field. So, after sending your barcode text with sendKeys method, send 'enter' directly after it. Note that you will have to import the selenium Keys class. See my code below.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

String barcode="0000000047166";
WebElement element_enter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='div-barcode']"));
element_enter.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath")).sendKeys(barcode);

element_enter.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); // this will result in the return key being pressed upon the text field
```